# Polynomials for the indicator function

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic-functions

The (one-variable) indicator function (or characteristic function) is defined as
$f_{t^*}:\mathbb{Z}_q\to \mathbb{Z}_q$ satisfying that
$f_{t^*}(t)=1$ if $t=t^*$ and $f_{t^*}(t)=0$, otherwise. (Here $t^*\in \mathbb{Z}_q$ is given to define the function.) More generally, in the case of multi-variable, we define $f_{t^*}:\mathbb{Z}_q^d\to \mathbb{Z}_q$,   $f_{t^*}(t_1, \cdots, t_d)=1$ if $\exists t_i$ such that $t_i=t^*$ and $f_{t^*}(t_1, \cdots, t_d)=0$, otherwise.

I am finding polynomials that can be used to represent these functions.
So far, I have found some for the one-variable case:

- **Using Lagrange Interpolation**: As $t, t^* \in \mathbb{Z}_q=\{0,1, \cdots, q-1 \}$ then such a polynomial should go through the points $(0,0), (1,0), $ $\cdots, $ $(t^*-1,0), (t^*, 1), $ $(t^*+1, 0),$ $ \cdots,$ $ (q-1,0)$. We can construct $f_{t^*}(t)=\frac{t(t-1)\cdots (t-t^*+1)(t-t^*-1)\cdots (t-q+1)}{t^*(t^*-1)\cdots (t^*-t^*+1)(t^*-t^*-1)\cdots (t^*-q+1)} (\bmod q)$ via the Lagrange Interpolation method. However, the polynomial has degree of $q-1$ and looks complicated to analyze.
- **Using Fermat's Little Theorem**: The Fermat's Little Theorem states that if $q$ is a prime number, then for any integer $a$ not divisible by $q$, the number $a^{q-1}=1 ~(\bmod q)$.  Then we can construct $f_{t^*}(t)=1-(t-t^*)^{q-1}~ (\bmod q)$, if $q$ is prime. This polynomial looks simpler but may still be not helpful in case $q$ is a very big integer.

**The question is whether are there any more polynomials other than those above?**

This question arose when I was trying to apply the idea at Section 4.2-4.3 of paper: https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2014/84410298/84410298.pdf to the indicator function.

Please help me if you have an idea!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you give us a bit of background on how this question arose? What sort of things do you know about it already?

Comment: @DavidRoberts, please see the updated question! Thank you very much! In case you cannot see the updated question, please see the following comments:

Comment: The (one-variable) indicator function (or characteristic function) is defined as
$f_{t^*}:\mathbb{Z}_q\to \mathbb{Z}_q$ satisying that 
$f_{t^*}(t)=1$ if $t=t^*$ and $f_{t^*}(t)=0$, otherwise. (Here $t^*\in \mathbb{Z}_q$ is given to define the function.) More generally, in the case of multi-variable, we define $f_{t^*}:\mathbb{Z}_q^d\to \mathbb{Z}_q$,   $f_{t^*}(t_1, \cdots, t_d)=1$ if $\exists t_i$ such that $t_i=t^*$ and $f_{t^*}(t_1, \cdots, t_d)=0$, otherwise.

I am finding polynomials that can be used to represent these functions. 
So far, I have found some for the one-variable case:

Comment: - **Using Lagrange Interpolation**: As $t, t^* \in \mathbb{Z}_q=\{0,1, \cdots, q-1 \}$ then such a polynomial should go through the points $(0,0), (1,0), $ $\cdots, $ $(t^*-1,0), (t^*, 1), $ $(t^*+1, 0),$ $ \cdots,$ $ (q-1,0)$. We can construct $f_{t^*}(t)=\frac{t(t-1)\cdots (t-t^*+1)(t-t^*-1)\cdots (t-q+1)}{t^*(t^*-1)\cdots (t^*-t^*+1)(t^*-t^*-1)\cdots (t^*-q+1)} (\bmod q)$ via the Lagrange Interpolation method. However, the polynomial has degree of $q-1$ and looks complicated to analyze.

Comment: - **Using Fermat's Little Theorem**: The Fermat's Little Theorem states that if $q$ is a prime number, then for any integer $a$ not divisible by $q$, the number $a^{q-1}=1 ~(\bmod q)$.  Then we can construct $f_{t^*}(t)=1-(t-t^*)^{q-1}~ (\bmod q)$, if $q$ is prime. This polynomial looks simpler but may still be not helpful in case $q$ is a very big integer.

Comment: The question is that is there any more polynomials that are simpler than those above. 
This question raised when I was trying to apply the idea at Section 4.2-4.3 of paper: https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2014/84410298/84410298.pdf to the indicator function.

Comment: Hope you can see my comments because my question was closed due to it seemed to be off-topic.

Comment: I see the edits, it looks like a reasonable question to me. I've voted to reopen

Comment: In the polynomial function constructed with Lagrange's interpolation formula, you want to make sure that the denominator does not vanish, therefore $q$ should be required to be a prime. On the other hand, even the edited version of the question could be found off-topic, because it asks about "simpler" functions without defining what "simple" means, therefore leaving it as a matter of subjective opinion.

Comment: Thank you @AlexM. I have just updated the question again to be clearer.

Comment: Thank you @DavidRoberts.

Comment: Not research level. And such a polynomial exists iff $q$ is squarefree.

Comment: Since the polynomial has $q-1$ roots, it *must* have degree at least $q-1$ if $q$ is prime. Moreover, there is a *unique* polynomial of degree $q-1$ with this property, as two polynomials represent the same function on $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$ iff their difference is divisible by $x^q-x$. (Thus, the Lagrange interpolation polynomial is exactly the same as what you get from Fermat’s little theorem, only written in a more complicated way.)

Comment: @reuns Actually, it exists only if $q$ is prime or $1$: if $p\mid q$ is prime, then $f_0(0)\equiv1\pmod p$, hence $f_0(p)\equiv1\pmod p$. If $p<q$, then $f_0(p)\equiv0\pmod p$, a contradiction. Thus, $q=p$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes obviously, thank you, the CRT only gives a polynomial function which is a unit iff $x=1$.

Comment: Oh, I missed that the question asks about the multivariate case. But it works pretty much the same as univariate (for prime $q$): every function $(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^d\to(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)$ is represented by a *unique* polynomial $f\in(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)[t_1,\dots,t_d]$ such that $\deg_{t_i}(f)<q$ for each $i$. All other polynomials representing the same function are of the form $f+\sum_i(t_i^q-t_i)h_i(\vec t)$. For the case of $f_{t^*}$, the unique representation with $\forall i\,\deg_{t_i}<q$ is $1-\prod_i(t_i-t^*)^{q-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your all discussions! They are very helpful to me!